# Get Text from Json and add it to String[]

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-arrayadapter

I want to fetch a text (some urls) from Json and add them straightly to a `String[]` in android. The text is like

`"http://www.androiddrawer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Subway-Surfers-screenshot-4-1.png","http://www.androiddrawer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Subway-Surfers-screenshot-4-2.png","http://www.androiddrawer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Subway-Surfers-screenshot-4-3.png","http://www.androiddrawer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Subway-Surfers-screenshot-4-4.png"`

I want to put this text into a String[]. I know I can use this method:

```
products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(0);
String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
```

But it gives me String not String[].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking your String

```
"http://www.androiddrawer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Subway-Surfers-screenshot-4-1.png","http://www.androiddrawer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Subway-Surfers-screenshot-4-2.png","http://www.androiddrawer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Subway-Surfers-screenshot-4-3.png","http://www.androiddrawer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Subway-Surfers-screenshot-4-4.png"
```

It seems that this can be converted into String[].

use like

```
String[] result = above_string_variable.split(",");
```

In your case

use

```
String[] result = c.getString(TAG_NAME).split(",");
```

instead of

```
String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
```

Comment: This will give him an array of strings but won't remove quotes around values.

Comment: @Gustek and where is quotes? I didn't understand what u are saying?

Comment: "value","value","value" if You split it by comas You are left with array {"\"value\"", "\"value\"", "\"value\"" }

Comment: Thanks dear. The answer was brilliant and efficient. But I should have removed quotation marks too.

Comment: Hey @NamikazeMinato feel free to update the answer. I will be happy.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
String[] result = new String[products.length()];
for(int i=0;i<products.length();i++) {

JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);
    result[i] = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
}
```